# Can I start an Instance of my IRC Bot (Twitch Chat Bot) from my website? Looking for answers that would make it easier

Tags: c#, .net, json, irc, twitch

**Main idea:** Having my own users press a button (after prefconfiguring the bot) on my website and starting an instance of my Bot that joins their channel.

**My idea of solving this problem:** Creating a JSON file that updates whenever a change is made on the website, and having a BotController App that starts the instances based on this data (asynchronously).
The JSON file would have Data like : ChannelName, Commands, RegularUsers, LastUpdate, CommandTimeout Rates, etc.. which would be fed to the instance creating method. (but then comes another issue , changing data while the bot is running)

**My issue:** This way of solving the problem seems to be a bit overcomplicated, and im looking for an easier way (if it exists). I wanna create a system like "Nightbot"'s except that this system is more League oriented and will only be available for my users. Also Im really new to C# therefor I have no idea how to make this Controller get the data for example every minute currently, but I'm sure i can look that up if i dig deeper. (links / examples appreciated)

**Plus info:** I started learning C# 1,5 month ago and I've spent a lot of time with it since. The bot is 70% done, im just finishing it up, cleaning up the code and adding more features but it seemed to be pointless if i can't make it 'user-friendly' and more public.

*ps.: Sorry if my english is broken here and there, it's my third language and im really tired. If any other information is required, I'll gladly update my question / answer.*

Comment: Is it a one bot for many channels ?

Comment: Exactly. But i'm also thinking about letting people give their own oauth key and use their own account as a bot.